# Dynamically creating and assigning names to movieclips AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, movie, creation

I have a movieclip that I need to duplicate dynamically based on an outside variable.
e.g. clip1, clip2, etc
This variable changes so I can't hardcode the number of times it occurs.

Is there a way to dynamically create this movieclip multiple times and align it according on the screen?

I wasn't able to find anything on Google..

Regards
Luben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a function that duplicates a DisplayObject. This function returns a new instance of the Class the provided object is:

```
function duplicateDisplayObject( dspObj:DisplayObject ):DisplayObject 
{
    var class_name:String = getQualifiedClassName( dspObj );
    var definition:Class = getDefinitionByName( class_name ) as Class;
    return new definition() as DisplayObject;
}
```

(MovieClip, Sprite, and Bitmap all inherit from DisplayObject)

Edit:

If you need to use it with MovieClips, you can simply:

```
var myDuplicate:MovieClip = duplicateDisplayObject( myOriginalMovieClip ) as MovieClip;
```

Comment: Thanks Julian just what I was looking for - a note If I use DisplayObject I cannot use .gotoAndPlay(). Changing it to MovieClip solves the problems.

Comment: That's true, but you don't need to change the duplicateDisplayObject function. Simply cast the return value when you use it. See my example above.

Comment: Please note the above function does not work for movieClips within other movieClips. Any Ideas on how to duplicate such objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
var clip:YourClip;

for(var i:uint=0;i<5;i++)
{
     clip = new YourClip();
     addChild(clip);
     clip.x = 20 + clip.width * i * 1.2;
     clip.y = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to just duplicate an instance of a clip. You can instantiate another instance of it's class though, and then adjust the position of it.

```
var clip1:MyClip = new MyClip();

var copies:int = 10;

for(var i:int = 0, i < copies; i++) {
    var clone:MyClip = new MyClip();
    clone.name = 'clip' + i
    clone.x = ....;
    clone.y = ....;
}
```